# Method setJSMainModulePath is not visible after attaching RN

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I'm following the [RN tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) and trying to include lib into an existing project. Line

```
.setJSMainModulePath("index")
```

drawn in red - method is not visible. I've tried to search it throughout the prj directory and found its declaration in `ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java`. From the location line I can see, that the file this declaration is in shown inside the node_modules folder - it seems to me like it's not included in the project.

[image]

Why it can't be found?